# How to filter out Yottaa bots traffic in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm using both Google Analytics and [Yottaa](http://yottaa.com) for my website. Yottaa bots send quite a lot a traffic (relatively to the normal traffic of my website), and thus my Google Analytics is kind of flooded by that.

I don't know how to tell Yottaa bots traffic and normal human traffic apart on Google Analytics. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier this month I wrote a detailed post ["How to segment and filter out robot traffic [in Google Analytics]" with step-by-step instructions and screenshots](http://blog.yottaa.com/2011/03/google-analytics-how-to-segment-and-filter-out-robot-traffic/). Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution.

Since Nov 4 2010 Yottaa bots identify themselves by "YottaaMonitor" in the User-Agent string (at least it's the name that appears in Google Analytics).

I created an "Advanced Segment" (i.e. a filter) with a single rule : Browser does not match YottaaMonitor. This segment now contains only the normal "human" traffic I wanted.

Problem solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question! Sorry that Yottaa support missed your question. There are two ways to deal with this:
1. Just as suggested by Martin Bouladour, you can add a "filter" to filter out all traffic from "YottaaMonitor" in Google Analytics. It is a clean solution;
2. Or you can use robots.txt file. See http://www.yottaa.com/how-to/block-yottaa-monitoring.